# Pyqtgraph - correct order of import statements?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Question in the title. In the imports below should QtCore and QtGui be imported from pyqtgraph or PyQt5 ?

My code works fine but looking at this I have bad code feeling -  I'm not sure how pyqtgraph patches pyqt5 and what the best practise is.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSplitter, QFrame,  QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, QTimer, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal


from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From any one, pyqtgraph detects if you have imported PyQt5 and establishes it as a backend. The [Qt.py file](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/Qt.py) is responsible for managing this logic.

For example, it is easy to verify that the module imported by pyqtgraph is the same as PyQt5 if PyQt5 is imported initially.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore as PyQt5QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui as PyQt5QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as PyQt5QtWidgets

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore as pgQtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui as pgQtGui
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets as pgQtWidgets

assert(pgQtCore == PyQt5QtCore)
assert(pgQtGui == PyQt5QtGui)
assert(pgQtWidgets == PyQt5QtWidgets)
```